# Correct contraction with to be (not)

Tags: difference, contractions

If I say: You are not Julie, what is the correct contraction?

- You're not Julie
- You aren't Julie

Comment: Please clarify why you think only one of those is correct.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think that only one is correct, I thought there was only one way to do contraction

Comment: Does [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/47404/you-arent-in-vs-youre-not-in/47406) answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

You are not Julie.

= You're not Julie.

= You aren't Julie.

Both types of contraction are okay.

Comment: You might mention that with the verb to be there are two possibilities in the present tenses.....

Comment: It happens with the verb 'to have' also : You haven't done it. You've not done it.

Comment: So,say that. :)